# Transición de CSS no se activa después del evento hover

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo un CSS en el cual la transición no se ejecuta después del evento hover. Pero si lo hace cuando en el inspector le cambio un valor en CSS del correspondiente `div`. La etiqueta que contiene la descripción del botón aparece en su posición final (sin transición) A continuación pongo el código:

```css
#menuVertical {
  max-width: 5%;
  z-index: 120;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #442351ff;
  top: 5em;
  left: 2%;
  padding: 0% 1% 1% 1%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menuVertical li {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

.iconoMenuPC {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding: 50% 0%;
}

#menuVertical .informacionMenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 133%;
  top: 20%;
  z-index: 119;
  height: 80%;
  width: 300%;
  padding-right: 50%;
  display: none;
}

.informacionMenu .descripcionItemMenu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.triangulo {
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid #f0ad4e;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
}

#menuVertical a:hover .informacionMenu {
  /*Aquí se ejecutará la '*/
  display: flex;
  left: 200%;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menuVertical" class="ocultoMovil">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/home.png" alt="icono home">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Inicio</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/servicios.png." alt="icono servicios">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Servicios</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/equipo.png" alt="icono equipo">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Equipo</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/proyectos.png" alt="icono proyectos">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Proyectos</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/contacto.png" alt="icono contacto">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Contacto</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image: Esta es la captura de pantalla]

Comment: He puesto el código como ejecutable para que se pueda ver corriendo en la propia pregunta. ¿Podrías [edit] la publicación para añadir una mejor descripción de la transición y cómo no funciona? No termina de quedar claro en la pregunta.

Comment: Y te damos la bienvenida al sitio (veo que es tu primera pregunta). Pásate por el [tour] para aprender más cuál es el funcionamiento general (y con ello ganar tu primera medalla). Un saludo y suerte :)

Comment: podrias ademas de hacer lo de @AlvaroMontoro poner imagenes online, para que se vea mas claro al momento de ejecutarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no se puede realizar una transición sobre `display: none` ya que la transición es algo progresivo y no se puede pasar de manera progresiva de un elemento que no está en la página (`display: none`) a que esté completamente en la misma, o está o no está, pero no puede estar "a medias".

Usa la propiedad `opacity` (`0` significa que estará oculto y `1` que estará visible con total nitidez) en su defecto.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
#menuVertical {
  max-width: 5%;
  z-index: 120;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #442351ff;
  top: 5em;
  left: 2%;
  padding: 0% 1% 1% 1%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menuVertical li {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

.iconoMenuPC {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding: 50% 0%;
}

#menuVertical .informacionMenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 133%;
  top: 20%;
  z-index: 119;
  height: 80%;
  width: 300%;
  padding-right: 50%;
  opacity: 0; /* NUEVO */
}

.informacionMenu .descripcionItemMenu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.triangulo {
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid #f0ad4e;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
}

#menuVertical a:hover .informacionMenu {
  /*Aquí se ejecutará la '*/
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1; /* NUEVO */
  left: 200%;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menuVertical" class="ocultoMovil">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/home.png" alt="icono home">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Inicio</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/servicios.png." alt="icono servicios">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Servicios</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/equipo.png" alt="icono equipo">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Equipo</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/proyectos.png" alt="icono proyectos">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Proyectos</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="iconoMenuPC" src="img/icons/contacto.png" alt="icono contacto">
      <div class="informacionMenu">
        <p class="descripcionItemMenu">Contacto</p>
        <div class="triangulo"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```